# Is there a pronunciation rule or sound change for the word 협력?

Tags: pronunciation

How do I pronounce 협력? Are there any rules that apply to it to change its immediately apparent pronunciation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. 협력 is [pronounced 혐녁](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=42484700).

This is the result of a combination of some standard pronunciation rules:

- ㅁㄹ => ㅁㄴ sound change

  - A 받침 of any of the closed-lip consonants (ㅂㅃㅁㅍ), followed immediately by an ㄹ, will cause the ㄹ to be pronounced as an ㄴ.
- ㅂㄴ => ㅁㄴ sound change

  - A 받칩 of ㅂ followed by any of the nasal consonants (ㅁㄴ) will cause the ㅂ to be pronounced as an ㅁ. (Like in 합니다)

Comment: Weird. To me there is a definite different in pronunciation of 협력 and 혐녁. Hyup-yeok as opposed to Hyum-neok. I guess when in spoken conversation the difference between blurs.

Comment: @PhonicsTheHedgehog 협력 is *definitely* always pronounced 혐녁 (As in the dictionary 발음 section in the link). But sound changes are often very hard for learners to pick up - it's super common for us to "hear" things that aren't there (or not-hear things that are) because of our expectations.

Comment: I suppose so! This is interesting.